# Itextpdf: The document has no pages error

Tags: android, itext, mpandroidchart

I have a problem with making a pdf file in my android app using ITextPdf. I'm trying to convert a MPAndroidChart linechart to a bitmap and save it to a pdf file.

Here's the code for saveToPdf() method:

```
private void saveToPdf() {
    Bitmap bitmap = saveChartToBitmap();
    Document doc = new Document();
    File pdfCreated = new File(getBaseContext().getFilesDir() , "PDFCreated.pdf");
    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(pdfCreated));
        doc.open();

        Image image = Image.getInstance(bitmap);
        doc.newPage();
        doc.add(image);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Pdf created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        doc.close();
    }
```

And my saveChartToBitmap() method:

```
private Bitmap saveChartToBitmap() {
    if (lineChart.getMeasuredHeight() <= 0) {
        lineChart.measure(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(lineChart.getMeasuredWidth(), lineChart.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        lineChart.layout(0, 0, lineChart.getMeasuredWidth(), lineChart.getMeasuredHeight());
        lineChart.draw(c);
        return b;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Don't know if something with my conversion to bitmat or creating an Image object is wrong but can't figure it out. I get: The document has no pages error. So I need advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an exception? Does `e.printStackTrace();` output anythingß

Comment: I get "The document has no pages." exception at doc.close();.

Comment: Yes, but that happens in the `finally` block of your `try-catch-finally` structure. Thus, an exception might have happened in the `try` block and then was processed in the `catch` block before the `finally` block was executed and ran into another error. I would assume the *The document has no pages." exception* merely is a follow-up of such an earlier exception.

Comment: As mentioned by Poyyamozhi Ramakrishnan the exception probably thrown in your `try` block might *not* be caught in the `catch` clause, in particular if it's a RuntimeException. You should move the `doc.close()` out of the `finally` block to the end of the `try` block to allow the original exception to show up.

Comment: Ok, you were right, I got rid of the finally block and I get NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method "'int com.itextpdf.text.Element.type()' on a null object reference" at doc.add() because my bitmap is null. Have to figure out another way to create bitmat.

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after opening document, always add an empty chunk to document so that you can avoid this exception.

doc.open;

doc.add(new Chunk(''));

Comment: While this may prevent the no-pages exception, it doesn't resolve the issue, the underlying `NullPointerException` - the op did solve that as explained in the op's own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `saveChartToBitmap()` method returns `null`. Also did you see the toast message.

Comment: Yeah, it returns null. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Instead of passing the bitmap to the Image.getInstance() method as an argument I converted it to a byte array and now It's working. Thanks